# Qtcreator can't find the class header file after promoting a widget to that class?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm a newbie in Qt and not that much experienced in C++ either.

I created simple Qt GUI app, but then I had to add the `mousepressevent` function on a `QLabel` type object, so I created the class which has the header file with following code:

```
#ifndef IMAGEACTION_H
#define IMAGEACTION_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEvent>

class imageaction : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit imageaction(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
signals:
    void Mouse_Pressed();
public slots:

};

#endif // IMAGEACTION_H
```

The `.cpp` file has the following code:

```
#include "imageaction.h"

imageaction::imageaction(QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
}

void imageaction::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    emit Mouse_Pressed();
}
```

In the `mainwindow.cpp` file added the line `#include "imageaction.h"` to include the header file and in the `.pro` file it's the following lines are also added:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    imageaction.cpp


HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    imageaction.h
```

But the program always gives the following error:

`C1083: Cannot open include file:'imageaction.h': No such file or directory`.

Could you say where I'm making the mistake? To make this class I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0CDMtfefB4)

Comment: are they in same dir as mainwindow.cpp?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory.

Comment: try to add this class via gui support: C++ Class Wizard, should work  http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-project-creating.html

Comment: I did add via the gui support. I just followed that video I added with the question. But somehow it doesn't work :(.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, "C1083: Cannot open include file:'imageaction.h': No such file or directory" error from your ui_*.h file. If that is the case, your issue regading promoting imageaction widget.

```
This may work
1. while promoting imageaction widget, uncheck "globalinclude".
     or
2. Update pro file with "INCLUDEPATH += path where mywidget.h"
```

Please check for more info [Promoting Widget](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23330)

Comment: For others who might come across this answer, this line from the link is what solved my problem: "When you’re defining a promoted widget in designer there’s a place to put “header file”. Put there the right include path, not just “mywidget.h”."

Comment: In addition to hjweide's comment, the path should be relative to the CMakeLists.txt where you add UI cpps as sources to your target

Answer (score 6):

For CMake, it needs to have include directory paths to work with. In CMakeLists this can be done by include directory directives. For Example:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

If the header files are in separate include folder then this should be written in CMakeLists:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's just your path in cmake, so just put this code in your CMakeLists.txt:
`target_include_directories(<YOUR PROJECT NAME> PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})`